# Fixed table layout overflow to the side

Tags: css, html-table

**Problem**

1. I have a fixed width table (which it must be) and one of the cells contains text
   that is too long to fit within it, so it overflows outside the cell to the right.
2. I need to have all the table cells' text to be aligned to the right.
3. I ideally don't want to change any of the markup.

**What I'm Looking For**

I'm in need of finding someway for the (text in the example) "longlonglong" to overflow to the left over the other previous cells and maintain it's aligned right state.

**Code**

HTML

```
<table width="120">
    <tr>
        <td width="30">text</td> 
        <td width="30">text</td>
        <td width="30">text</td>
        <td width="30">very longlonglong text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/eVkgz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/eVkgz/1/

```
<table width="120">
    <tr>
        <td width="30">text</td> 
        <td width="30">text</td>
        <td width="30">text</td>
        <td width="30">
            <div id="container1">
                <div id="container2">very longlonglong text</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

td {
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#container1 {
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#container2 {
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is in part what I'm after, but I ideally don't want to change / add HTML, do you feel this outcome could be achieved with CSS alone?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a variable height of the cells?

If not:

Place a div inside the td and this CSS:

```
td {
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
td div {
   position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Hello, This seems to push the text in the cell outside of the table and places it to the far right of page?

Answer (score 0):

Add  word-break: break-all; to yours td style:

```
td {
word-break: break-all;
text-align: right;
border: 1px solid black;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I need the text string "longlonglong" to be all on one line.